# How do I change the colum name of model in Django Admin?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

My admin.py file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from . models import contactEnquiries

class ContactAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display =  ['cn_name', 'cn_email', 'cn_number']

    @admin.display(description='Name')
    def cn_name(self, obj):
        return obj
    

admin.site.register(contactEnquiries, ContactAdmin)
```

I want to display the column titles as - Name, Email, Number instead of `'cn_name', 'cn_email', 'cn_number'` in the admin panel. I tried the above code but I am not sure how to do it? Can anyone please help?

Comment: If you set a `verbose_name` in your model fields, that should be reflected in the admin column text, e.g `cn_name = models.CharField(..., verbose_name="name")`

Comment: Will that affect the actual column names in the database?

Comment: No. It's just a human readable variant. There's already a default verbose_name with underscores changed to spaces, so you would just be overriding that default.

Comment: Understood. It worked well for me. Thanks for explaining :) Appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `verbose_name` in your model itself without affecting your database or any other function. Like this `column_name = models.CharField(verbose_name="name you desire")` and that will change the name of your column in django admin for you.

In your case you use the following code:

```
class contactEnquiries(model.Models):
      cn_name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Name", your other config)

      #your all other columns here and you can user verbose_name in all your model columns.
```

You can read the documentation here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/options/#verbose-name

Answer (score 2):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from . models import contactEnquiries

class ContactAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display =  ['cn_name', 'cn_email', 'cn_number']

   
    def cn_name(self, obj):
        return obj.cn_name
    
    cn_name.short_description = 'Name'

    def cn_email(self, obj):
        return obj.cn_email
    
    cn_email.short_description = 'Email'


admin.site.register(contactEnquiries, ContactAdmin)
```

Comment: This is a good approach as well. Apparently, I got it resolved using ```verbose_name``` but thanks for the idea. Appreciate it :)